# Paramiko [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 172.16.127 Using Pycharm and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ssh, pycharm, paramiko

I'm using tkinter to build a desktop app. Also, using Paramiko for an ssh connection. The app has a 'connect' button calling the function

```
def checkAuth():
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, 22, username=userName, password=password)
```

Here is the call for the function in the tkinter app.

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/tracer/tracer.py", line 18, in checkAuth
ssh.connect(host, 22, username=userName, password=password)
File "C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\tracer\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 368, in connect
raise NoValidConnectionsError(errors)
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 172.16.127.6 or fe80::d99d:ff15:3fc1:482e

connectButton = Button(connect, text="Connect", width=6, command=checkAuth)
```

But getting "paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 172.16.127.6" as the output."

I can run just this function as a stand along script and it connects fine. I can ssh via cmd and putty to the host without issue. It's only seems to be when using the function within the tkinter app that I encounter this.

All help much appreciated.

Comment: that host ip doesn't look right, is it a typo?

Comment: The IP address is wrong. An IP address is made up of four components, not three.

Comment: My apologises. It was a typo! I've edited the original post. ".6" was missing.

Comment: Where is it being called in your tkinter app?  Can you post the code on how it's  called?

Comment: Thanks @noobius. I've re edited including the button command that calls this function.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue when trying to connect to a remote windows machine  but i don't use Tkinter, all i want is to connect to the machine and run a python script which is already there

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I ssh into a remote machine:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import paramiko

def setup_ssh_client(host):
    print("establishing ssh connection....")
    client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    home = os.path.expanduser("~")
    ret = os.path.exists(os.path.join(home, "somekey.pem"))
    if not ret:
        print("Unable to locate pem key, upload aborted....")
        return None

    private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(os.path.join(home, "somekey.pem"))
    try:
        client.connect(hostname=host, username="bob", pkey=private_key)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print("connected")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
    for line in stdout:
        print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
    return client

window = tk.Tk()
connectButton = tk.Button(window, text="Connect", width=6, command=setup_ssh_client)
connectButton.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I tried this with tkinter and it connect fine when clicked on the button.  I don't see much different than what you're doing, maybe add client.load_system_host_keys() and see if it helps.  Just use your username and password instead of private key to authenticate instead of what I'm doing in my example.

Comment: unfortunately no luck with adding client.load_system_host_keys(). Not sure I understand your comment about no using a private key. Could you explain?

Comment: @EricPraline You can authenticate with username and password, or if you setup public/private key with you ssh server, then you can authenticate with the ssh server using your private key (the server have your public key and will perform authentication using encryption/decryption with your private key).  It's another mechanism to authenticate.

Comment: @EricPraline I updated my full sample code, if you try that and still not able to connect, then it's probably something else that blocked the connection.  Try a different host if possible, see if the host is still up and that you can still ssh in from putty.  Still doesn't make sense that it would work in a stand alone script (without tkinter).

Comment: The issue i'll have with the private key is, this app is intended for the users to log into many different ssh servers, not just the same one each time. It is strange that it works outside of tkinter. I really appreciate the time you've taken.

Comment: I've managed to get the tikinter call back also if that helps at all. I've updated that original post to include it.

Comment: @noobius I need some help in configuring public and private keys. I want to trigger windows server from my linux machine.